# How to search for maximum element in an array?

Tags: c

I have this code and it works fine. However, it can't seem to pass all test case. The program fails if the input size is divisible by 3? how do I fix that? What can I do about my code?

````
int maxArrayElem(int arr[], int size){
    int tempArr;
    int flag = 0;
    int max;

    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        if(arr[i]>arr[0]){
            max = arr[i];
        }else if(arr[0]>arr[i]){
            max = arr[0];
        }
        else{
            tempArr = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[0];
            arr[0] = tempArr;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
int main(){
    int size;

    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    int arr[size];
    int maxE;
    
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    maxE = maxArrayElem(arr,size);
    printf("Maximum element: %d", maxE);
}```
````

Comment: Write more test cases and keep testing it until you find what inputs cause it to fail. Then you can run the program in a debugger to find out where/why it is failing.

Comment: `int arr[3] = { 2, 3, 1 };` seems like it should fail.

Comment: Also, please give the complete wording of the requirements. For example, did they say anything about the maximum number of inputs?

Comment: @user3386109 you are right. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @kaylum yea im sorry.

Comment: Why compare against `arr[0]` instead of `max` ? So `max = arr[0];` then loop `i = 1` and compare `if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];`?

Comment: Now that you have a simple example that fails, you can look at the code with a debugger, and see why the code fails. Or you can grab a pencil and paper, and read one line of code at a time and figure out what the code is doing. Or you can fill the code with a whole bunch of printfs that display the variables at each line of code, and figure out what's going wrong that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a lot of work, if this the objective...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    int size;

    printf ("Enter size of array: " );
    scanf( "%d", &size );
    /* omitting test for failure */

    int userVal = INT_MIN, maxE = INT_MIN;
    
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        printf( "Enter element %d: ", i+1 );
        scanf( "%d", &userVal );
        /* omitting test for failure */

        if( maxE < userVal ) maxE = userVal;
    }

    printf( "Maximum value: %d", maxE );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the function called `maxArrayElem` can be optimized into:

```
int maxArrayElem(int arr[], int size){
    int max = arr[0];

    for(int i = 1; i<size; i++){
        if(arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

where a variable called `max` initially stores the value of `arr[0]` and see if the next element of the array greater than the current max and if it's the case then make this element the new maximum element and so on...